# How do I use VBA to insert an image to the second page of a word doc

Tags: excel, vba, image, ms-word

I am writing an Excel program that uses inserts a set of images dynamically into a Word document.

```
Sub Insertnote(WordDoc As Object, note As String, LeftPos As Integer, TopPos As Integer, Pagenum As Integer)
    Dim imgShape As Object
    Dim imagePath As String
    Dim pageRange As Object
    
    Debug.Print (note)
    
    imagePath = "C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\personal\misc and archives\vba experiments\SimpleMusik\" & LTrim(note) & ".png"
    
    ' Get the range of the specified page
    Set pageRange = WordDoc.GoTo(What:=2, Which:=2, Count:=1)
    
    ' Insert the image as a shape
    Set imgShape = WordDoc.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=imagePath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
    
    ' Set the image as the background
    WordDoc.Background.Fill.UserPicture imagePath
    
    ' Set the position of the image
    imgShape.Left = LeftPos
    imgShape.Top = TopPos
End Sub
```

After a certain condition, the line

```
WordDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbCr & Chr(12)
```

is used to add a new page and subsequent images are added to the second page.

How do I modify this code to insert an image to the nth page of a Word document (assuming that it exists).

When I run this code, all of the images end up on the first page

Comment: Your values in the Goto are incorrect.  What:=2 is selecting Tables, not pages. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdgotoitem.  It would be better if you add a reference to the Word object model then you can use the correct enumeration members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Pagenum` is the relevant page number then amend your `Insertnote` Sub to:

```
Sub Insertnote(WordDoc As Object, note As String, LeftPos As Integer, TopPos As Integer, Pagenum As Integer)
    Dim imgShape As Object
    Dim imagePath As String
    Dim pageRange As Object
    
    Debug.Print (note)
    
    imagePath = "C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\personal\misc and archives\vba experiments\SimpleMusik\" & LTrim(note) & ".png"

    ' get the start of the page
    Set pageRange = GetStartOfPage(WordDoc, Pagenum)

    ' if we got a valid start-of-page
    If Not pageRange Is Nothing Then

        ' Insert the image as a shape ... use the start of the page as the 'anchor'
        Set imgShape = WordDoc.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=imagePath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Anchor:=pageRange)
        
        ' Set the image as the background
        WordDoc.Background.Fill.UserPicture imagePath
        
        ' Set the position of the image
        imgShape.Left = LeftPos
        imgShape.Top = TopPos
    Else
        '  no such page
        Debug.Print "Page " & Pagenum & " does not exist" ' customise for your needs
    End If
        
End Sub
```

... this is mostly your original `Insertnote` but now gets the page, tests it is valid and uses it as the 'anchor' (see code comments for more info) ... you will need to customise the code in the `Else` block to handle the page not existing if that can happen.

And in the same Module (or another standard Module), add:

```
Function GetStartOfPage(doc As Object, lNum As Integer) As Object ' Word.Document, Word.Range
    Dim rng As Object ' Word.Range
    On Error GoTo errExit ' in case page does not exist
    ' get the page
    Set rng = doc.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages(lNum).Rectangles(1).Range
    ' collapse to start of page
    rng.Collapse 1 ' wdCollapseStart
    Set GetStartOfPage = rng
errExit:
End Function
```

This will insert the relevant picture right at the start of the relevant page.

You should remember that the concept of 'pages' in Word is somewhat fluid ... if you change various page setup settings then what is initially the start of a particular page may no longer be so.

Comment: Thanks for this code. I literally just pasted it into my existing code and it worked.